# Ribbon Customization form in Devexpress

Tags: vb.net, devexpress

I am developing a ribbon form using Devespress and I need to let the end user to be able to customize the ribbon items so the I used the following code

```
RibbonControl1.AllowCustomization = True
```

However, when the customization form is fired, the logo of Devexpress is still there, knowing that I have changed the application icon to the End user icon.

```
RibbonControl1.ApplicationIcon = CType(resources.GetObject("RibbonControl1.ApplicationIcon"), System.Drawing.Bitmap)
```

Is there a way to change that?

1. The Ribbon Customization form is a runtime form and I have no access to it.
2. I already changed the form icon to the icon I need:

[image: VB settings]

3. When I run the application, here is the result:

[image: Ribbon Customization form].

4. The ribbon control form:

[image: Ribbon control form]

Comment: Are you using a form or a Ribbon form?

Comment: i am using a ribbon form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer based on devexpress official support email.

```
ribboncontrol.optionscustomizationform.formicon
```

this property will change the ribbon customization form icon.

Ex: I have added the following code to the MAIN form designer (the form that contains the ribbon)

```
RibbonControl1.OptionsCustomizationForm.FormIcon = CType(resources.GetObject("$this.Icon"), System.Drawing.Icon)
```

this will change the customization form's icon to the MAIN form's icon.

Answer (score 0):

On the ribbon form `DevExpress.XtraBars.Ribbon.RibbonForm` (not the ribbon itself), set the icon property to the icon you want to use:

[image]

You should see this show up in design time as well as runtime.

Also, bear in mind if your ribbon is merged (MDI), then the child form might inherit the application icon of the parent form, so check on that if this is a child form.

Comment: actually i did that before and it didn't work. please recheck my post, i have updated it.

Comment: What is the `RibbonStyle` property set to on the ribbon?  I'd like to see all properties, but I understand that's not exactly practical in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`RibbonControl.OptionsCustomizationForm`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraBarsRibbonRibbonControl_OptionsCustomizationFormtopic) property to set the icon for customization form.

[image: OptionsCustomizationForm property]

Here is the result:

[image: Result]